# How to compress data

Tags: ios, swift, compression, memory-layout

I'm trying to compress data to improve the space complexity, but I'm not sure if I'm incorrectly compressing data or incorrectly measuring the size.

I tried the following in the Playground.

```swift
import Foundation
import Compression

// Example data
struct MyData: Encodable {
    let property = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
}

// I tried using MemoryLayout to measure the size of the uncompressed data
let size = MemoryLayout<MyData>.size
print("myData type size", size) // 16

let myData = MyData()
let myDataSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myData)
print("myData instance size", myDataSize) // 16

func run() {
    // 1. This shows the size of the encoded data
    guard let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myData) else { return }
    print("myData encoded size", encoded) // 589 bytes

    /// 2. This shows the size after using a first compression method
    guard let compressed = try? (encoded as NSData).compressed(using: .lzfse) else { return }
    let firstCompression = Data(compressed)
    print("firstCompression", firstCompression) // 491 bytes

    /// 3. Second compression method (just wanted to try a different compression method)
    let secondCompression = compress(encoded)
    print("secondCompression", secondCompression) // 491 bytes
    
    /// 4. Wanted to compare the size difference between compressed and uncompressed for a bigger data so here is the array of uncompressed data.
    var myDataArray = [MyData]()
    for _ in 0 ... 100 {
        myDataArray.append(MyData())
    }
    guard let encodedArray = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myDataArray) else { return }
    print("myData encodedArray size", encodedArray) // 59591 bytes
    print("memory layout", MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: encodedArray)) // 16
    
    /// 5. Compressed array
    var compressedArray = [Data]()
    for _ in 0 ... 100 {
        guard let compressed = try? (encoded as NSData).compressed(using: .lzfse) else { return }
        let data = Data(compressed)
        compressedArray.append(data)
    }
    guard let encodedCompressedArray = try? JSONEncoder().encode(compressedArray) else { return }
    print("myData compressed array size", encodedCompressedArray) // 66661 bytes
    print("memory layout", MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: encodedCompressedArray)) // 16

    /// 6. Compression using lzma
    var differentCompressionArray = [Data]()
    for _ in 0 ... 100 {
        guard let compressed = try? (encoded as NSData).compressed(using: .lzma) else { return }
        let data = Data(compressed)
        differentCompressionArray.append(data)
    }
    guard let encodedCompressedArray2 = try? JSONEncoder().encode(differentCompressionArray) else { return }
    print("myData compressed array size", encodedCompressedArray2) // 60702 bytes
    print("memory layout", MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: encodedCompressedArray2)) // 16
}

run()

// The implementation for the second compression method
func compress(_ sourceData: Data) -> Data {
    let pageSize = 128
    var compressedData = Data()
    
    do {
        let outputFilter = try OutputFilter(.compress, using: .lzfse) { (data: Data?) -> Void in
            if let data = data {
                compressedData.append(data)
            }
        }
        
        var index = 0
        let bufferSize = sourceData.count
        
        while true {
            let rangeLength = min(pageSize, bufferSize - index)
            
            let subdata = sourceData.subdata(in: index ..< index + rangeLength)
            index += rangeLength
            
            try outputFilter.write(subdata)
            
            if (rangeLength == 0) {
                break
            }
        }
    }catch {
        fatalError("Error occurred during encoding: \(error.localizedDescription).")
    }
    
    return compressedData
}
```

The `MemoryLayout` object doesn't seem to be helpful in measuring the size of encoded arrays whether or not they're compressed.  I'm not sure how to measure a struct or an array of struts without encoding them with `JSONEncoder` which already compresses the data.

The before/after compression for the single instance of `MyData` (#1, #2, and #3) seems to show that the data is being properly compressed going from 589 bytes to 491 bytes. However, the comparison between an array of uncompressed data and an array of compressed data (#4, #5) seems to show that the size increased from 59591 to 66661 *after* the compression.

Finally, I tried using a different compression algorithm `lzma` (#6).  It reduced the size to 60702 which is lower than the previous compression, but it still wasn't smaller than the uncompressed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a bit of confusion out of the way first: `MemoryLayout` gives you information about the size and structure of the layout of a type at compile time, but can't be used to determine the amount of storage an `Array` value needs at runtime because the size of the `Array` *structure itself* does not depend on how much data it contains.

Highly simplified, the layout of an `Array` value looks like this:

```
┌─────────────────────┐                        
│        Array        │                        
├──────────┬──────────┤    ┌──────────────────┐
│  length  │  buffer ─┼───▶│     storage      │
└──────────┴──────────┘    └──────────────────┘
  1 word /   1 word /                          
  8 bytes    8 bytes                           
 └─────────┬─────────┘
           └─▶ MemoryLayout<Array<UInt8>>.size
```

An `Array` value stores its length, or `count` (mixed in with some flags, but we don't need to worry about that) and a pointer to the actual space where  the items it contains are stored. Those items aren't stored as part of the `Array` value *itself*, but separately in allocated memory which the `Array` *points* to. Whether the `Array` "contains" 10 values or 100000 values, the size of the `Array` structure remains the same: 1 word (or 8 bytes on a 64-bit system) for the length, and 1 word for the pointer to the actual underlying storage. (The size of the storage buffer, however, is *exactly* determined by the number of elements it is able to contain, at runtime.)

In practice, `Array` is significantly more complicated than this for bridging and other reasons, but this is the basic gist; this is why you only ever see `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:)` return the same number every time. [And incidentally, the size of `String` is the same as `Array` for similar reasons, which is why `MemoryLayout<MyData>.size` also reports `16`.]

In order to know how many bytes an `Array` or a `Data` effectively take up, it's sufficient to ask them for their `.count`: `Array<UInt8>` and `Data` are both collections of `UInt8` values (bytes), and their `.count` will reflect the amount of data effectively stored in their underlying storage.

---

As for the size increase between step (4) and (5), note that

- Step 4 takes 100 copies of your `MyData` and joins them together before converting them to JSON, while
- Step 5 takes 100 copies of *individually compressed* `MyData` instances, joins *those* together, and then re-coverts them to JSON

Step 5 has a few issues compared to step 4:

1. Compression benefits *heavily* from repetition in data: a bit of data compressed and repeated 100 times won't be nearly as compact as a bit of data repeated 100 times, then compressed, because each round of compression can't benefit from knowing that there's another copy of the data that came before it. As a simple example:

   - Let's say we wanted to use a form of [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to compress the string `Hello`: there isn't a lot we can do, except maybe turn it into `Hel{2}o` (where `{2}` indicates a repetition of the last character `2` times)
   - If we compress `Hello` and join it 3 times, we get might get `Hel{2}oHel{2}oHel{2}o`,
   - But if we first joined `Hello` 3 times and then compressed, we could get `{Hel{2}o}{3}`, which is much more compact
2. Compression also typically needs to insert some information about how the data was compressed in order to be able to recognize and decompress the data later. By compressing `MyData` 100 times and joining all of those instances, you're repeating that metadata 100 times
3. Even after compressing your `MyData` instances, re-representing them as JSON *decreases* how compressed they are because it can't represent the binary data exactly. Instead, it has to convert each `Data` blob into a [Base64-encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which causes it to *grow* again

Between these issues, it's not terribly surprising that your data is growing. What you actually want is a modification to step 4, which is compressing the *joined* data:

```
guard let encodedArray = try? JSONEncoder().encode(myDataArray) else { fatalError() }
guard let compressedEncodedArray = try? (encodedArray as NSData).compressed(using: .lzma) else { fatalError() }
print(compressedEncodedArray.count) // => 520
```

This is *significantly* better than

```
guard let encodedCompressedArray = try? JSONEncoder().encode(compressedArray) else { fatalError() }
print(encodedCompressedArray.count) // => 66661
```

---

As an aside: it seems unlikely that you're actually using `JSONEncoder` in practice to *join* data in this way, and this was just for measurement here — but if you actually are, consider other mechanisms for doing this. Converting binary data to JSON in this way is very inefficient storage-wise, and with a bit more information about what you might actually need in practice, we might be able to recommend a more effective way to do this.

If what you're actually doing in practice is encoding an `Encodable` object tree and then compressing *that* the one time, that's totally fine.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I didn't think about the base64 growing the size again. You're right in that I'm only using `JSONEncoder` at the end again just to measure the size, but does that mean the compressed result would actually turn out to be smaller? Also, I should've been clearer with my question. I need the individual element compressed instead of the entire array compressed because I'm using the compressed elements in data structures that require searching & sorting.

Comment: For example, I'm compressing most of the content within `MyData` and will have an uncompressed unique identifier to conform to `Comparable` or `Equatable` and they will be used in a binary tree or a linked list, etc. From what you explained, it seems like if the data I'm trying to compress isn't relatively sizeable, the time complexity for actually performing the compression will outweigh the small reduction in size. Would this be a correct line of reasoning?

Comment: @Kevvv Yeah, to be a bit clearer, the compressed data will almost always be smaller than its base64-encoded string, which is what `JSONEncoder` will output. For instance, `MyData().property.data(using: .utf8)` is 574 bytes long; compressing that UTF-8 data with `.lzma` yields 428 bytes; the base64-encoded version of that compressed data is back up to 572 bytes again. So using `JSONEncoder` to compare sizes won't give you a good idea of what's actually going on. Accessing `.count` directly on a `Data` will give you a much better clue.

Comment: @Kevvv As for whether the cost of compressing the data is worth it, that depends entirely on the actual structure of the real-world data you're dealing with and what your needs are. You're absolutely right that there's a trade-off here: small data can't compress as well, but will cost some minimum amount of time to compress, so it might not be worth it. But the specifics of that trade-off, you'll need to continue to benchmark. Avoid using `JSONEncoder` to look at sizes, and try to get some accurate release-mode timings of how long compression takes.

Comment: For small _enough_ data like what you have here in this post, it's very likely to be a wash: the data won't compress very much, but it also won't take very long to compress... At that point, other factors might come into play, like keeping the code simpler and easier to read and debug, rather than the effect compression is effectively having.